# razor syntax - foreach loop

Tags: razor

```
@foreach (string s in "1,2,3".Split(',')) {
  s is equal to @s<br/>
}
```

I want to spit out:
s is equal to 1
s is equal to 2
s is equal to 3

But I'm getting all sorts of errors because Visual Studio thinks that what is between the {}'s is code, but I want it to be markup.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Just saw this [on ScottGu's blog this morning](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx): use `@:` before that line:

```
@foreach (string s in "1,2,3".Split(',')) {
  @: s is equal to @s<br/>
}
```

Alternately, use the `<text />` tag:

```
@foreach (string s in "1,2,3".Split(',')) {
  <text>s is equal to @s<br/></text>
}
```

Comment: `<text>` is nice for multiple lines.

Answer (score 19):

[Scott Guthrie just answered that this morning](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx).
Change it to

```
@foreach (string s in "1,2,3".Split(',')) {
  @: s is equal to @s<br/>
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
@foreach (string s in "1,2,3".Split(',')) {
  <text>s is equal to </text>@s<br/>
}
```

I think it is because you are parsing text outside of brackets so Razor is thinking it is code, try using the razor text tag above, this parses exactly the same as @: but (for me at least) is a bit more intuitive (it won't parse the  tags)