# Finding Roles MVC 4 Simple Membership

Tags: asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

My Action

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (var ctx = new _dbContext())
    {
        return View(ctx.UserProfiles.OrderBy(x => x.UserId).ToList());
    }
}
```

I want to display roles with UserId and UserName how can i do that??

Update:
View Model

```
public class AccountIndexViewModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Roles { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@using GoldCalculator.Models
@model IEnumerable<AccountIndexViewModel>
            @foreach (var user in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@user.UserId</td>
                    <td>@user.UserName</td>
                    <td>@user.Roles</td>
                    <td> @Html.ActionLink("X", "Delete", new { id = @user.UserName }, new {  @class = "deletebtn"})</td>
                </tr>
            }
```

The output is System.String[]

Comment: what's your problem with displaying that? You don't know how to do that in view or what?

Comment: Dunt know how to get to Roles.. User profiles do not have role attribute.. i am feeling like foolish dunt know why i pasted this code... Just wanna know how to get into roles and show them with  username in Simple Membership

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have enabled roles in your application and that you have already created some roles:

```
using WebMatrix.WebData;
///blah blah blah...

///inside some action:
var roles = (SimpleRoleProvider)Roles.Provider;

var allRoles = roles.GetAllRoles();
```

Getting role for specific user:

```
var userRoles = roles.GetRolesForUser("admin@user.com");
```

Answering you new question, try this:

```
var model = ctx.UserProfiles.OrderBy(x => x.UserId);
var newModel = from ab in model
            select new 
            {
                UserName = ab.UserName,
                UserId = ab.UserId,
                Role = roles.GetRolesForUser(ab.UserName)
            };
```

You are assigning value to variable that already has been declared and apparently data types don't match.

Comment: System.String[] I have this Output... I think there is some conversion problem... I updated the Question..

Comment: Because these are ROLES, not one role, you have to iterate through them to get all the roles that user is assigned to

Comment: use foreach loop http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463000/razor-syntax-foreach-loop but it should be ok just to access first element in the array

Comment: I know about loops where to add that..?

Comment: You can put it wherever you need